# Moodle Installation Character set

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, installation, moodle

I had Moodle 3.2.3 version, I moved to my website another hosting provider and want to install with upgrade the system 3.62.

I getting an error on the "**Checks**" page while Installing as you see below:

```
Your database uses Antelope as the file format.
Full UTF-8 support in MySQL and MariaDB requires the Barracuda file format.
Please switch to the Barracuda file format.
See the documentation MySQL full unicode support for details.

For full support of UTF-8 both MySQL and MariaDB require you to change your MySQL setting
'innodb_large_prefix' to 'ON'. See the documentation for further details.
```

Error fixing page : https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/MySQL_full_unicode_support#File_format

[Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnXdc.jpg)

I usign CPanel and phpMyAdmin and Managing with Navicat program.

How I would pass this checks?  Thanks.

Comment: If Moodle did not blindly create `VARCHAR(255)`, those instructions would not be required.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions in the Moodle docs for converting the format to Barracuda: https://docs.moodle.org/en/Administration_via_command_line#Converting_InnoDB_tables_to_Barracuda

You will need command line access to run these scripts (command line access is highly recommended for running a Moodle site).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But If we don't have access to Command line or shell what we would do?

Comment: First recommendation would be to find a hosting provider that allows CLI access - a dedicated Moodle hosting provider should allow that (and you probably want to be using a dedicated provider, unless this is only a very small test site). If not, then a Google search suggests: https://darrenoneill.eu/?p=194 (but I've not tried it).